# Equivalent to setting termios c_iflag=IGNPAR using C# SerialPort class

Tags: c#, c, serial-port, termios

I'm attempting to port an old C application which talks to a serial device into C#.
C applications sets the following fields when setting up serial communication:

```
newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
newtio.c_oflag = 0;
```

I do not see a way to replicate this in C# and I believe this causes the serial device to behave differently when "9C" is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.parity(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Public  enum Parity 
Even    Sets the parity bit so that the count of bits set is an even number.
Mark    Leaves the parity bit set to 1.
None    No parity check occurs.
Odd     Sets the parity bit so that the count of bits set is an odd number.
Space   Leaves the parity bit set to 0.
```

**You should be interested in `None`**

create the port with this constructor:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public SerialPort(
    string portName,
    int baudRate,
    Parity parity
)
```

set the parity value with this method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.parity(v=vs.110).aspx

```
_serialPort.Parity = SetPortParity(_serialPort.Parity);
```